Difference between 駕駛 and 駕馭?
They both mean to control, pilot something. A car, a horse, a plane.
So what's the difference? Is one a colloquial term and one formal?

駕駛: drive; pilot (used to describe operating man-made transportation, for example, driving a car, or piloting a plane/ ship. We ride a horse, not driving it because a horse is not a man-made machine)
駕馭: control; keep under control (mostly used in the metaphorical sense, describe controlling something natural like people, a river, or horses)
Example:
共和黨無法駕馭川普 (The Republican Party cannot control Trump)
以水壩駕馭長江 (Controlling the Yangtze River with Dams)
駕馭馬匹是一門技能; 駕馭下屬是一門藝術 (Control horses is a skill; control underlings is an art)

駕駛:Mainly refers to the real actions of driving a car and riding a motorcycle
駕馭:It refers to ability. For example, I can control this person. It means I can control this person.
